# $(this).closest("tr").remove(); Not working for new elements

Tags: jquery, html

I've been battling with this problem for a while but since I'm not seasoned in jQuery, I need a little help.

To put it simply, I'm using buttons to add and remove rows in a table.

I've managed to get this .on() event to fire for the dynamically generated elements, however the `$(this).closest("tr").remove();` only seems to work for the first element before any others are added. What is occurring to make it stop working after new lines are added?

From what I see using other examples here on SO is that I'm using the correct event delegation...

Here's a JSFiddle outlining what I've got so far: https://jsfiddle.net/vsgvLuam/4/

Comment: Your issue is that append() doesn't work this way. Inspect rendered HTML markup and check relevant append() DOC

Comment: Looking at the code. The new `<td>'s that are appended are not within a row (`<tr>`)

Comment: Oooh, nice catch, I'll look into re-writing the append code and try again, I'll respond with the outcome in a short while.

Comment: Try to do a single append with all the new html in it. As it is right now the browser is trying to correct the unclosed tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsgvLuam/6/)

Instead of appending the rows and cells separately, append them all at once so you know the `<td>`'s are inside the row (`<tr>`)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer for its simplicity, because I now have a better understanding about how the `.append()`s work and I get to keep a nice clean formatting. Cheers wmash!

Comment: No problem @MattDunne. glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem. `append()`, does not return the element which is added, but the element to which it was added.

```
$('#printerOptions').find('tbody:last').append('<tr>')
```

You need to get the new `tr`, and append the rest, so that the columns are added in the `tr`.

```
$('#printerOptions').find('tbody:last').append('<tr>').find('tr:last')
```

Then add the next items.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vsgvLuam/8/)

As better solution is to use a variable with new `tr` and append later, you can use [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/vsgvLuam/5/).

Comment: @Esko No it does not. Try this in your console. `$( 'body' ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );`

Comment: As much as this answer works and is valid, after learning more about how the appends work I'm in favour of writing just the one `append()` but using `' + '` to join my lines. It just looks cleaner to me. Thank you for the contribution though. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What I tried on your code :

```
$("#printerOptions").on("click", ".addOption", function(event) {
  $('#printerOptions').find('tbody:last').append('<tr><td><button style=" width: 50%;" class="btn btn-primary removeOption">Remove Rule</button></td><td><select style="width: 100%;" autocomplete="off" form="tablequery" name="this[]"><option value="Store ID">Store ID</option><option value="Item Name">Item Name</option><option value="Item Code">Item Code</option><option value="Shipping Type">Shipping Type</option></select></td><td><input style="width: 100%; box-sizing:border-box;" name="that[]" form="tablequery" value=""></td><td><select style="width: 100%;" autocomplete="off" form="tablequery" name="printer[]"><option value="40569">Officejet_Pro_8600</option><option value="40570">_192_168_1_65</option><option value="40571">AdobePDF9</option><option value="142555">_192_168_2_64</option><option value="142556">Pantum_P3000_</option><option value="142621">Oce_ColourWave_700</option><option value="147124">_192_168_1_62</option></select></td></tr>');
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same problem. So, I successfully identified the problem. The problems is caused by append(). Instead of appending only  `<td>` append the entire   `<tr><td></td></tr>`. Here is an example

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var html = '<tr><td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="year[]"></div></td><td><button type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button></td></tr>';
        var x = 1;
        var max = 5;
        $('#add').click(function(){
            if(x <= max)
            {

                $('#form-table').append(html);
                x++;
            }
        
        });
        $('#form-table').on('click','#remove',function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            x --;
        })
    })
```